# How to create a column name with space in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, space

I want to create a column with a space in its name. In MySQL I just created this using back ticks, but in SQL Server that causes an error. Are there any possibilities to create a column name with a space?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
create table space_check
(
`roll num` int,
name varchar(50)
)
```

Can anybody tell me how to create this?

Comment: Consider using underscore or some variation of camel-case instead of a space... enclosing things in square brackets etc can become tedious.

Comment: I would highly encourage you to avoid doing this. While it's possible, it can become a pain to have to write queries against these columns because you always have to remember to include brackets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use brackets in SQL-Server

```
create table space_check
(
  [roll num] int,
  name varchar(50)
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Give the column name within `Square brackets`.

```
create table space_check
(
  [roll num] int,
  name varchar(50)
)
```

It was not a good practice. Try to create using underscore(roll_num) or caps(rollNum).

Answer (score 4):

use bracket `[` to create `columns` with spaces.

```
create table space_check
(
[roll num] int,
name varchar(50)
)
```

However it is not a good practice. Try using RollNum or `rollNum` or `roll_num`.